# Wpf controls size is coming small/blurry in wpf ViewBox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mvvm, wpf-4.0

I have an usercontrol in wpf window. In usercontrol, I have put all the controls inside the viewbox so that if the user resize the window it does not effect the scaling of the usercontrol.

```
<Viewbox >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 ---------------------------
 ---------------------------
</Grid>
    </Viewbox>
```

In the first image, when the window is not maximized the usercontrols controls are coming as below i.e. small and blurry. Size of the controls are not constant.

[image]

if the user maximized the window, the usercontrol is coming fine as below:

[image]

Kindly suggest how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
[TextBlock inside a Viewbox - strange rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408726/textblock-inside-a-viewbox-strange-rendering)

And try playing with `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode` values on Viewbox (assuming the controls n the screenshot are rendered as text with fonts, not bitmapimages.